# Preprocessing step to load update bundles (plugins) when starting an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I want to enhance my Eclipse RCP application with following capability: when starting the app a bootstrap mechanism should check a folder whether there are update bundles/plugins available in it and, if so, install them via the BundleContext. However, the problem is that this would mean that also the bundle that contains my IApplication implemenation can be updated. So the preprocessing step must be after starting OSGi, but before starting the app. Is it possible to do this? (Other approaches like overwriting the old bundles before starting the application are not feasible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up using an [Eclipse adaptor hook](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Adaptor_Hooks). Using this approach, I can load the required bundles before the default bundles of my app are loaded. As I commented on Peter's answer, the OSGi start levels are seemingly ignored for an Eclipse RCP app (correct me if I'm wrong). Also creating a startup extension for the *org.eclipse.ui.startup* eclipse extension point does not help, because it is triggered too late. If you are interested in the Eclipse adaptor hook approach, you can find a good tutorial on [this page](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/23/how-to-track-lifecycle-changes-of-osgi-bundles/).

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of stuff that OSGi start levels were designed for. You might also want to checkout Apache Felix Fileinstall (works fine in Eclipse).

Comment: Thank you Peter! However the autostart option of my bootstrap loader bundle is ignored if I start the Eclipse application. (The BundleActivator of the bootstrap bundle is never called.) If I rework the app to an OSGi framework application, all works fine but I cannot use the convenience of an Eclipse RCP app (e.g., built-in splashscreen support).

Comment: Do the splash screen from a bundle on a very low start level. I do not know how the eclipse launcher works but it would surprise me if you could not set start levels. And for autostart, there is an option for that in the config file. You might also want to look at bnd(tools). bndtools is I guess also an RCP app but made as a real OSGi framework app.